# Remove AD Group Membership based on $Attribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am working on the second part of a script I've been making. Both are concerning $attribute which can either have the value of M or N. For any users in our org with a value of M, the first part of the script will add them to the group. This part works-- I have a list of members populated which seems to be correct.

The second part of the script needs to scan members of this group for anyone who now has an $Attribute value of N, and then should remove them from the group. I'm having trouble with this part-- specifically keying off of this custom attribute so a working list of members will populate. Here's more or less what I'm trying to do to remove membership.

```
import-module activedirectory
$notmems = @()
$notmems += get-adgroupmember -identity <groupname> | where-object{$_.extensionattribute6 -like 'N*'}
foreach ($notmem in $notmems) {remove-adgroupmember -identity appkronosmanagers -members $noman}
```

What happens: the first part successfully calls the group members and seemingly populates them into the array. The where-object part seems to not be able to recognize ad object attributes or I am just calling them wrong. The command will either return a list of everyone or no one. I have mostly been messing with changing -like to -notlike to -notmatch hoping my logic there may have been wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `Get-Adgroupmember` does not return attributes that include the extension attributes. You will have to pipe into `Get-ADUser -Property extensionAttribute6 | where extensionAttribute6 -like 'N*'`

Comment: If `$notmems` contains all of the users you want to remove, you don't even need a loop if you are moving from the same group. `-Members` takes an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$notmems = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity <groupname> |
    Get-ADUser -Property extensionAttribute6 | Where extensionAttribute6 -like 'N*'

Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity <groupname> -Members $notmems -WhatIf
```

You will have to remove the `-WhatIf` switch if you are satisfied with the command's intended operation.

**Explanation:**

`Get-ADGroupMember` returns `ADPrincipal` objects with only a limited set of properties (`distinguishedName`, `name`, `objectClass`, `objectGUID`,  `SamAccountName`, `SID`). In order to see more properties that would normally be associated with an `ADUser` object, you can call `Get-ADUser`.

Piping an `ADPrincipal` that is a user into `Get-ADUser -Property extensionAttribute6` returns an `ADUser` object with the default property set plus `extensionAttribute6`. You can return a subset of those properties with `Select-Object -Property Property1,Property2`.

Since `Remove-ADGroupMember` uses the `-Identity` parameter to find the group and accepts a collection of `ADPrincipal`s for the `-Members` parameter, no loop is necessary to remove multiple users from one group.

---

As an aside, `$notmems = @()` and `$notmems +=` are not necessary here. If your command returns multiple objects, `$notmems` will automatically be a collection or array with a simple `$notmems =` assignment. If you are always requiring a collection even if one object could be returned, you can just surround the command with `@()`.

If your group could have nested groups, you may need to update your `Get-ADGroupMember` command to not throw errors when piping into `Get-ADUser`:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity <groupname> | Where objectClass -eq 'user' |
    Get-ADUser -Property extensionAttribute6 | Where extensionAttribute6 -like 'N*'
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I was wondering if the objects I was calling didn't have the attribute/all the information I was looking for.

I am getting a new error when trying to apply this new-found logic. Powershell says it cannot bind/convert the custom attribute across translating objects (I hope I said that right). Does this error mean anything to you?

Answer (score 0):

As [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings) explained, the `extensionAttribute6` is not part of the objects returned by the `Get-ADGroupMember` cmdlet and you will have to use `Get-ADUser` to get that property.

However, according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps), the `-Identity` parameter for `Get-ADUser` is a single AD object, not an array. The parameter can also get this object through the pipeline.
This would mean you should loop through the results of `Get-ADGroupMember` and check the property for each user inside that loop.

Hope that helps

```
$notmems = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity <groupname> | Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq 'user'} | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Get-ADUser -Properties extensionAttribute6 | Where-Object {$_.extensionAttribute6 -like 'N*'}
}
```

Once satisfied with the results in `$notmems` you can remove them using

```
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity <groupname> -Members $notmems
```